# Программа записывет байты чисел, а нужны сами числа

Tags: c

Программа должна записать значения переменных a, b, c в test.txt, и потом программа должна "узять" эти числа с файла для обчисления периметра треугольника. Но программа останавливает своё действие после ввода значения с, а в файле остаются их символы.
Сам код программмы:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int a, b, c, P;
    FILE *file;
    int *d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20);
    int *e = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20);
    int *f = malloc(sizeof(int) * 20);

    printf("Введи сторону a: ");
    scanf("%i", &a);
    printf("Введи сторону b: ");
    scanf("%i", &b);
    printf("Введи сторону c: ");
    scanf("%i", &c);

    if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Файл не возможно открыть или создать\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sprintf(d, "%i", a);
    fwrite(d, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    sprintf(e, "%i", b);
    fwrite(e, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    sprintf(f, "%i", c);
    fwrite(f, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    rewind(file);
    fclose(file);

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fread(d, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fread(e, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fread(f, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    P = d + e + f;
    printf("Периметр треугольника%i", &P);
    fclose(file);

    free(d);
    free(e);
    free(f);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "непонятные символы", "не понятные символы, а какая-то абракадабра" - вы записываете бинарные данные - 4 байта для каждого целого.

Comment: Ну, вы сохранили данные в бинарном виде, что ж вы хотите, прочитать его как текст? Перегоняйте в строку через `sprintf` и пишите её.

Comment: Ну это же не меняет смысл вопроса?

Comment: @nicolia Простите, но вопроса тут нет. И ваша программа делает ровно то, что должна: сохраняет в файл байты, которые вы ей указываете и столько, сколько указываете.

Comment: @nicolia Вы не видите различия между числом в машине и тем, десятичным, которым обычно оперируют люди. Если вы запишите 1 байт со значением например 65, то увидите 1 символ - букву 'A', но для машины это все так-же 65. Просто потому, что машина хранит данные в двоичном виде, причем по 8 бит в байте. И при этом 1 байт - обычно 1 привычный нам символ. В одном "символе" машина хранит число от 0 до 255. А нам в привычной нам десятичной системе для записи числа 255 приходится писать 3 символа ... Так что записывая бинарные данные вы их по символам не прочитаете, а машина прочитает

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует открыть файл в бинарном режиме, если вы действительно хотите сохранять данные в бинарном представлении.

```
if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "wb")) == NULL)
                              ^^^^^^
```

Иначе, если хотите записать данные в текстовом режиме, то используйте, например, функцию `fprintf` вместо `fwrite`

Функция `fwrite` записывает внутреннее представление последовательности байтов, содержащихся по адресу, указанному в первом параметре.

Так что в текстовом редакторе полученные символы не будут иметь особого смысла, если только вы не записываете какую-нибудь строку.

Comment: и что, тогда символы в файле станут понятными?

Comment: @Igor Для меня - да.:) В текстовом режиме может дописывать, например, в конец файла символ конца файла